# Angular Material datatable. How can I put dynamic table (array in array)?

Tags: arrays, angular, datatable, angular-material

I have  a array of data. I want to put in a datatable but the array has array of data.
I don't know how I can do it, I thought with a *ngFor but I don't know where I should put it.

I want to show

```
codigo | nombre (departamento) | estacion (nombre) | mes | año | Tmaxima
```

of every departamento, Every departamento has a lot of estacion and every estacion has a lot of data like "mes, ano and Tmaxima"

The code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wdz2u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I'll show you the code. This is a example because the data I got it a BD.

**TableComponent :**

```
export class AppComponent {
datos= [{
codigo: 1,
departamento: "Tolima",
estaciones: [
  {
    nombre: "Estacion 1",
    latitud: "la1",
    longitud: 232,
    datos: [{ mes: 1, ano: 1983, Tmaxima: 32 }, { mes: 2, ano: 1983, 
Tmaxima: 32 }]
  },
  {
    nombre: "Estacion 2",
    latitud: "la2",
    longitud: 232,
    datos: [{ mes: 1, ano: 1990, Tmaxima: 32 }, { mes: 2, ano: 1990, 
 Tmaxima: 32 }]
  }
]
}, {
  codigo: 2,
  departamento: "Other",
  estaciones: [
    {
      nombre: "Estacion 1 other",
      latitud: "la1",
      longitud: 232,
      datos: [{ mes: 1, ano: 1983, Tmaxima: 32 }, { mes: 2, ano: 1983, 
 Tmaxima: 32 }]
    },
    {
      nombre: "Estacion 2 other",
      latitud: "la2",
      longitud: 232,
      datos: [{ mes: 1, ano: 1990, Tmaxima: 32 }, { mes: 2, ano: 1990, 
  Tmaxima: 32 }]
    }
   ]
 }
 ] 
displayedColumns: string[] = ["codigo", 
"nombre","estacion","mes","ano","Tmaxima"]
listaData: MatTableDataSource<any>

constructor() {
this.listaData = new MatTableDataSource(this.datos);
}

}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
<mat-table [dataSource]="listaData"  >    

<ng-container matColumnDef="nombre">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Nombre</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.departamento}} </mat- 
cell>
</ng-container>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="codigo">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Codigo</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.codigo}} </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="estacion">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Estacion</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.estaciones[0].nombre}} 
 </mat-cell>      
 </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="mes">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Mes</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">   </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="ano">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Año</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">   </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="Tmaxima">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Tmaxima</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  </mat-cell>
 </ng-container> 

 <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" ></mat-header-row>
 <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" ></mat-row> 
 </mat-table> 
 </div>
```

The only solution I found was this: convert the data in

```
    data2=[ {codigo:"",  
     departamento:"",   
     estacion:"",   
     nombre:"",
     latitud:"",
     longitud:"",
     ano:"",
     mes:"",
     Tmaxima:"" } ]
```

and this way I can get the data in the html... But this way is not nice..

Comment: how would you like your table look in the end ?

Comment: @AmitBaranes In this link you can see how looks like at the end https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wdz2u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to nest ngFor loops - below is an example displaying some of your data in a  simple HTML table, so it's clear what is happening:

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let dato of datos">
        <td>{{dato.departamento}}</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr *ngFor="let estacione of dato.estaciones">
                    <td>{{estacione.nombre}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've added this example to [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5b2pcv). Hopefully this will be enough information to point you in the right direction - the principle would be exactly the same for a mat-table.

You would use the following code to add a nested table to a cell in your Material Table:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="InnerTable">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Estaciones</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <table>
            <tr *ngFor="let estacione of element.estaciones">
                <td>{{estacione.nombre}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

And then add 'InnerTable' to your column definitions:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ["codigo", "nombre","estacion","mes","ano","Tmaxima","InnerTable"]
```

Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ozmdcm). You could use a second Material table, but I think this would be very busy visually. Unless you really need it, I would just use a standard HTMl table.

Comment: Yes, this is a solution. I have implemented it  but How is it possible in agular material?.

Comment: I think it will be visually busy to nest one Material table within another. If it was me, I would use the Angular Material table for the 'outer' data, and then a simple HTML table, styled with CSS, for the inner table, where needed. Something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ozmdcm

Comment: I agree with @MattSaunders , i think you should order the data as wanted or change the styling.. the solution you are looking for is to nested

Comment: @JhoanSaavedra - NP Jhoan. If it's helped you out can you upvote / accept answer?